# How to make a remove button in a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, enums, listbox

I am new to stackoverflow. Below is my project which I am currently working on, a beginner one let's say.
Until so far, I managed to create an add button. So basically, what this program does is to show available items and rented items. You select the item and the amount you want to rent and you press the add button to add it to the rented list. Now I am trying to do the opposite, at first I thought it was easy, but apparently it isn't. Also, how can I sort the items by ProductType? Like PS3 and Xbox 360 should in consoles, Monitor and usbs should be in accessories and so on, using a combobox. Thank you for your help!

```
        item_name = new List<string>()
        { 
            "Arduino", "USB 2TB ", "USB 120GB", "USB 32GB ",
            "Apple iPad", "Apple Pencil", "Adapter for Arduino",
            "Arduino camera", "Canon Lens", "Xbox 360", "PS3" ,
            "Apple iPhone 8", "Google Chromescast", "Samsung Monitor"
        };
        item_amount = new List<int>()
        {
            10, 20, 15, 14, 9, 7, 23, 9, 3, 4, 5, 7, 2, 6
        };
        item_rented = new List<int>()
        {
            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        };
    }


    private void ShowInfoRentedItems() //SHOWS INFO ABOUT RENTED ITEMS
    {


        this.lb_rented.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < item_name.Count; i++)
        {
            this.lb_rented.Items.Add(item_name[i] + "  rented: " + item_amount[i]);
        }



    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //ADD BUTTON
    {
        
        int index = lb_available.SelectedIndex;
        if (index < 0) { return; }
        MessageBox.Show(item_name[index] + " rented succesfully");


        string text = lb_available.SelectedItem.ToString();
        lb_available.Items[index] = " ";

        
        item_amount[index] -= int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        item_rented[index] += int.Parse(textBox2.Text);


        ShowInfoAvailbe(item_name, item_amount);

        

        this.lb_rented.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < item_rented.Count; i++)
        {
            if (item_rented[i] > 0)
            {
                this.lb_rented.Items.Add(item_name[i] + " rented: " + item_rented[i]);

            }
        }
    }

    private void ShowInfoAvailbe(List<String> stuff, List<int> sth) // SHOWS WHICH ITEMS ARE AVAILABLE
    {
        this.lb_available.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < item_name.Count; i++)
        {
            this.lb_available.Items.Add(item_name[i] + "  avaialable: " + item_amount[i]);
        }
      


    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //BUTTON TO SHOW INFO
    {
        // shows all available items

        ShowInfoAvailbe(item_name, item_amount);
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowInfoRentedItems();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = lb_rented.SelectedIndex;
        if (index < 0) { return; }
        MessageBox.Show(item_name[index] + " rented succesfully");


        string text = lb_rented.SelectedItem.ToString();
        lb_rented.Items[index] = " ";


        item_amount[index] += int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        item_rented[index] -= int.Parse(textBox2.Text);


        ShowInfoAvailbe(item_name, item_amount);

    }


}
```

}

Comment: I think that in ListBox you should better use your own class as item and only override ToString() method to pretty print that list item.

Comment: Yes, at the very least you should have a `public class Item { public string Name { get; set; } public int Amount { get; set; } }` and populate a list of that class. This way the properties of an item are stored together. You could also use these to populate a list of rented items, or create a new class that has an `Item` along with rental properties, like: `public class Rental { public Item Item { get; set; } public DateTime RentDate { get; set; } public DateTime DueDate { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 0):

Here I have example for Item class.

```
public class Item 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    
    public int Rented { get; set; }
    
    public Item (string name, int amount, int rented)
    {
        Name = name;
        Amount = amount;
        Rented = rented;
    }
    
    public void Rent()
    {
        if (Amount > 0)
        {
            Amount--;
            Rented++;
        }
    }
    
    public void Return()
    {
        if (Rented > 0)
        {
            Amount++;
            Rented--;
        }
    }
    
    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return $"{Name} - Amount: {Amount} - Rented: {Rented}";
    }
}
```

And then you can easily manage items in your ListBox. These are event handlers for buttons in your form.

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(new Item("NAME", 10, 1)); // constructor parameters (name, amount, rented)
}

private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        listBox.Items.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, I tried to use what you've sent me but, it shows nothing. Basically the items I have in the rented list need to go back to the available list, for example: There are 10 Arduinos available and I borrow 5, in the rented list it will shows that there are 5 Arduinos rented and the amount of Arduinos from the available list lowers, so there will be 5 Arduinos availalbe. What I want to do is once I press the remove, the amount of rented goes back to available. However, I'd like to thank you for your answer and the fact that you're helping me means a lot :)

Comment: So if I understand right you have one list for rented items and another for available?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //BUTTON REMOVE AN ITEM
    {
        int index = lb_rented.SelectedIndex;
        if (index < 0) { return; }


        string text = lb_rented.SelectedItem.ToString();


        item_amount[index] += int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        item_rented[index] -= int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

        string productName = text.Split('|')[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < lb_available.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lb_available.Items[i].ToString().Split('|')[0].Contains(productName))
            {
                int newValue = int.Parse(lb_available.Items[i].ToString().Split('|')[1].Replace("available: ", "")) + 1;
                item_amount[i] = newValue;
                item_rented[i] -= int.Parse(this.textBox2.Text);
                string bruh = lb_available.Items[i].ToString().Split('|')[0] + "|available: " + newValue;
            }
        }
         private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //BUTTON REMOVE ALL RENTED ITEMS
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lb_rented.Items.Count; i++)
        {

        }
    }
```